# Error starting a Pyro Name server

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, networking, ip, pyro

I have an Amazon ec-2 instance, with public ip 52.62.132.33.

Trying to start a name server pops the below error message.

```
(venv)[ec2-user@ip-172-31-6-10 ~]$ pyro4-ns -n 52.62.132.33
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/venv/bin/pyro4-ns", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ec2-user/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pyro4/naming.py", line 561, in main
    hmac=options.key)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pyro4/naming.py", line 369, in startNSloop
    daemon = NameServerDaemon(host, port, unixsocket, nathost=nathost, natport=natport, storage=storage)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pyro4/naming.py", line 251, in __init__
    super(NameServerDaemon, self).__init__(host, port, unixsocket, nathost=nathost, natport=natport)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pyro4/core.py", line 901, in __init__
    self.transportServer.init(self, host, port, unixsocket)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pyro4/socketserver/threadpoolserver.py", line 103, in init
    self.sock = socketutil.createSocket(bind=bind_location, reuseaddr=Pyro4.config.SOCK_REUSE, timeout=Pyro4.config.COMMTIMEOUT, noinherit=True, nodelay=Pyro4.config.SOCK_NODELAY)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pyro4/socketutil.py", line 285, in createSocket
    sock.bind(bind)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Starting the Name server with a private IP address was fine, but then I can't access the server from outside the network.

How to make it so Pyro is accessible from outside network?

Comment: Try binding on 0.0.0.0 instead.  Also, are you even allowed to expose a service on port 9090? (Pyro's default port for the name server)

Comment: 0.0.0.0 starts the name server

I can even connect to it from outside using the controller:

pyro4-nsc -n 52.63.77.156 list
--------START LIST 
Pyro.NameServer --> PYRO:Pyro.NameServer@0.0.0.0:9090
('    metadata:', (u'class:Pyro4.naming.NameServer',))
--------END LIST 


However I can't lookup the name server from code: 

ns = Pyro4.locateNS(host='52.63.77.156')
Traceback (most recent call last):
 ....
  File "/...../site-packages/Pyro4/naming.py", line 504, in locateNS
    raise e
Pyro4.errors.NamingError: Failed to locate the nameserver

Comment: Don't know about Amazon's EC2 network configuration then, but have a look at this https://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/tipstricks.html#pyro-behind-a-nat-router-firewall  perhaps you can find some things to try out there.